# Ruby system command fails Apache(Passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, r, apache, passenger

Attempting to build statistics into a side project via Rserve- Everything works in testing and rails console but in production under:
apache(passenger), Rails 4, ruby-2.3.0.

the commands work in the rails console on the production box and I've confirmed that:

- /bin/R is in the rails production (apache) path.
- system "R CMD Rserve" works as expected in rails console on production host with production environment loaded

In production running Apache(Passenger):

- system "R CMD Rserve" returns false
- $?.inspect  returns   -> Process::Status: pid 11144 exit 2

The exit status 2 is throwing me off because it indicated a missing keyword or command, or permission problem.

Anybody run into this? I think the issue is in passenger but the limited output is making this hard to debug..

Comment: You do not actually say that you have installed the R package Rserve (since it's not in the priority="high" list)  nor mention what version of R you have installed.

Comment: It's installed and in the path - works on the host via rails console, which is why I believe it to be a passenger issue. First thoughts were it needed to be in the right path (confirmed it is because the exit status of 2 ) or needed a tty to execute (don't know how to confirm this, yet).